# OutOfMemoryException issue using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

Our application is image resource heavy. Currently we don't have provision of sending images depending on device resolution from the server. The images sent from the server are generally of high resolution (around 900 X 900). I have few queries :
1) Will the image downloaded and stored in file disk cache will be of same size as the original size in server.

2) Once the image is saved in file disk cache, how is the image processed to bring it in the in-memory cache. Are the bitmap image stored in in-memory cache will be transformed to lower resolution depending on device resolution?

3) If the target image height and width is not known then how can we scale down the bitmap image as per device resolution? As per our requirement, it is not possible to give fixed width and height to imageview. There is resize(int, int) method but the problem is, we can't change the image height and width in some cases. Ideally, there should be some solution to downscale the image size by % (lets say 20%).

Crash does not occur always as it depends of memory.

Comment: This is not the Picasso issue, you must be doing intensive work that is consuming memory due to which you are receiving this issue. Based on my exp. it is  the best lib. I have used, because one of the app is full of images from Server. So please check for  any memory leaks in your code base

Answer (score 0):

You can use **android:largeHeap="true"** to request a larger heap size, but this will not work on any pre Honeycomb devices. On pre 2.3 devices, you can use the VMRuntime class, but this will not work on Gingerbread and above.

The only way to have as large a limit as possible is to do memory intensive tasks via the NDK, as the NDK does not impose memory limits like the SDK.

Alternatively, you could only load the part of the model that is currently in view, and load the rest as you need it, while removing the unused parts from memory. However, this may not be possible, depending on your app.

```
Example:
<application android:largeHeap="true" ....</application>
```